# Drag file into the NSTextView, show one warning dialog

Tags: objective-c, macos

ALL:

I have one NStextView and when I drag one ".mp4" file into the TextView, a warning dialog will be shown:

Do you really want to copy the contents of the dragged items into the text?

How can I block this warning dialog?
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: The warning dialog you describe is not any standard AppKit behavior I've ever seen or heard of. Text views by default insert the file path for files dropped into them, not the contents of the file.